# New definition of a field

Tags: soft-question, field-theory

**Definition of a field** : A field is any set of elements that satisfies the field axioms ( see the table ) for both addition and multiplication and is a commutative division algebra.
[image]

**New definition** : $R$ is field if and only if for every $a \neq 0$ in $R$, $ax =1$ has one solution in $R$.

> My question : I am only familiar with the first definition and I am not getting how second definition is a definition of a field? Form where it has emerged in mathematics

Comment: What makes you think that is a field?

Comment: It must be assumed that $R$ is already a commutative ring.

Comment: As you have written the question, you have replaced 10 axioms with one and that one contains two undefined elements 0 and 1. If you meant something else, you should modify the statement of your question to reflect what you fully mean.

Comment: R is commutative ring with 1

Comment: @sssss: "R is commutative ring with 1" is exactly the union of all the other axioms in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It emerges naturally when one tries to solve equations:

For example the equation

$$5x = 2$$

has no solution over the integers, but when the rational numbers are introduced, we get the (exactly one) solution $x=\frac{2}{5}$. In fact the rationals form a field.

Notice further: it suffices to solve equations of the form $ax=1$, since the equation $ay = b$ can then be solved by multiplying both sides by $b$ and getting the solution as $y=bx = ba^{-1}$.

Comment: Your answer assumes that $R$ is a commutative ring with 1. The OP doesn't assume that in the statement of his or her question. Also how do you know that $5\ne 0$ in $R$?

Comment: @ploosu2 Thanks for the answer, but could add more detail how new definition is a field.

Comment: Ok, maybe I won't delve into the definitions since these are already tabulated. And I assumed the rational numbers in the example, so $5\neq 0$